# How UCT in MCTS selection phase avoids starvation?

Tags: monte-carlo-tree-search, upper-confidence-bound

The first step of MCTS is to keep choosing nodes based on Upper Confidence Bound applied to trees (UCT) until it reaches a leaf node where UCT is defined as

$$\frac{w_i}{n_i}+c\sqrt{\frac{ln(t)}{n_i}},$$

where

- $w_i$= number of wins after i-th move
- $n_i$ = number of simulations after the i-th move
- $c$ = exploration parameter (theoretically equal to $\sqrt{2}$)
- $t$ = total number of simulations for the parent node

I don't really understand how this equation avoids sibling nodes being starved, aka not explored. Because, let's say you have 3 nodes, and 1 we'll call it node A is chosen randomly to be explored, and just so happens to simulate a win. So, node A's UCT$=1+\sqrt(2)\sqrt{\frac{ln(1)}{1}}$, while the other 2 nodes UCT = 0, because they are unexplored and the game just started, so by UCT the other 2 nodes will never be explored no? Because after this it'll go into the expansion phase and expansion only happens it reaches a leaf node in the graph. So because node A is the only one with a UCT $> 0$ it'll choose a child of node A and it will keep going down that node cause all the siblings of node A have a UCT of 0 so they never get explored.

Comment: Note that for those 2 unvisited nodes in your example, we do not have UCT = $0$. It's technically undefined (due to a division by $n_i = 0$), but if we want to pretend that division by $0$ isn't undefined, the most "sensible" value to assign to it would probably be $\infty$ (infinity). And if you assume that all unvisited nodes have a value of $\infty$, you basically arrive at [Cohensius' answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/26315/1641)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First explore the nodes A,B,C once.

For reference see this paper by David Silver and Sylvain Gelly, [Combining Online and Offline Knowledge in UCT](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29651027_Combining_Online_and_Offline_Knowledge_in_UCT)

> If any action from the current state $s$ is not represented in the tree, $\exists a \in \mathcal{A}(s),(s, a) \notin \mathcal{T},$ then the uniform random policy $\pi_{\text {random }}$ is used to select an action from all unrepresented actions, $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}(s)=\{a \mid(s, a) \notin \mathcal{T}\}$.